# Convert R list to dataframe with missing/NULL elements

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

Given a list:

```
alist = list(
  list(name="Foo",age=22),
  list(name="Bar"),
  list(name="Baz",age=NULL)
 )
```

what's the best way to convert this into a dataframe with name and age columns, with missing values (I'll accept NA or "" in that order of preference)?

Simple methods using `ldply` fail because it tries to convert each list element into a data frame, but the one with the NULL barfs because the lengths don't match. Best I have at the moment is:

```
> ldply(alist,function(s){t(data.frame(unlist(s)))})
  name  age
1  Foo   22
2  Bar <NA>
3  Baz <NA>
```

but that's pretty icky and the numeric variable becomes a factor...

Comment: Kind of annoying that `check.rows=FALSE` still gives an error about rows having different numbers of observations...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A comment mentioned wanting only a single loop, which can be achieved with [@flodel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793965/892313) just by putting the body of the two loops together:

```
rbind.fill(lapply(alist, function(f) {
  as.data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), f))
}))
```

giving

```
  name age
1  Foo  22
2  Bar  NA
3  Baz  NA
```

Answer (score 18):

Step1: remove `NULL` items

```
non.null.list <- lapply(alist, Filter, f = Negate(is.null))
```

Step2: stack everything together:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(lapply(non.null.list, as.data.frame))
#   name age
# 1  Foo  22
# 2  Bar  NA
# 3  Baz  NA
```

---

**Edit**: In case you had a variable that is `NULL` for all your list items, it would not show up in your final output. If instead, you'd like a column filled with `NA`, the first step should not remove `NULL`s but replace them with `NA`s:

Step 1 alternative: replace `NULL` with `NA`:

```
non.null.list <- lapply(alist, lapply, function(x)ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))
```

Comment: That second step was the subject of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753091/convert-mixed-length-named-list-to-data-frame/15753384#15753384, for which Josh O'Brien had a longer but more scalable answer.

Comment: I'm holding out for a solution that only has one loop/apply step... Otherwise this seems to crack it.