# "unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'" when writing dataframe in csv

Tags: r

I have below dataframe

```
df_Place:
    Name|Places
    ----+-----------------------
    abc |delhi
    bcd |mumbai,delhi
    cde |chennai,hyderabad,delhi
    def |mumbai
    efg |bangalore,mumbai
    ghi |delhi,bangalore
```

I wanted to have places in form of a matrix so I did below operation

```
df_Place$matrix<-as.matrix(strsplit(df_Place$Place,","))
```

I get below dataframe

```
Name|Places                 |matrix
----+-----------------------+------------------------------
abc |delhi                  |delhi
bcd |mumbai,delhi           |c("mumbai","delhi")
cde |chennai,hyderabad,delhi|c("chennai","hyderabad","delhi")
def |mumbai                 |mumbai
efg |bangalore,mumbai       |c("bangalore","mumbai")
ghi |delhi,bangalore        |c("delhi","bangalore")
```

now while trying to write this into csv
`write.csv(df_Place,"tx.csv")`
I get below error:

> Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  :
> unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'**

but if I remove the matrix column then it gets written successfully.

I know that it will be very basic, but can someone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you please output/share an example of the produced data.frame

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you

Comment: It is easier to produce an answer if you output the data (using dput) so users can read it in and manipulate it right away. Already did it myself and provided an answer (see below)

Comment: thanks. will out put the data from next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with writing a matrix (with multiple dimensions) to a df in which multiple cols have no dimensions (vector). I found this solution to work (see [Outputting a Dataframe in R to a .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291283/outputting-a-dataframe-in-r-to-a-csv))

```
# First coerce the data.frame to all-character
df_Place2 = data.frame(lapply(df_Place, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# write file
write.csv(df_place2,"tx.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` library

```
fwrite(df_Place, file ="df_Place.csv")
```